# Starter Gear On Riding Mower

Tags: engine, starting, lawnmower

The starter gear teeth on my lawn mower has been sheared off. As a result it is not engaging the flywheel. When I turned the key the first time, the flywheel engaged but the mower did not start (the choke was not engaged), so I tried it again, and that's when it started to make a high pitched 
noise. Could there be extra stress from the flywheel that caused it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0xn974nnbhukwi/IMG_4287.JPG?dl=0

**Sound clip:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/uclm4nrwjh7ui1c/JD111%20Starter.m4a?dl=0

Any ideas what might have caused this to happen?

Comment: As you can see, the teeth are made of a fibrous material. They are designed to take abuse and give instead of the starter ring gear. These are designed to be replaced. Look online, find the correct gear (looks like a B&S engine), and replace it. Looks like the same type I replaced before.

Comment: I stripped mine on a battery that was questionable. Not quite enough juice to engage the starter gear, so it only engaged partially and it was stripped grinding on the ring gear. After you replace the gear, make sure the battery is up to snuff...

Comment: @Paulster2  think you could make that an answer?  I think it's a good one.